Update Maven repository with specific Java version
I have about 100 dependencies in my pom.xml.
I tried to update them with mvn versions:use-latest-releases, but the updated dependencies’ Java version is higher than my Java version.
My Java version is 1.8, and some of them are 11 or above.
If I use those updated dependencies, will there be issues because their Java version exceeds my Java version?
I cannot use IDEA. Is there any tool that can help me update dependencies and ensure their Java version is 1.8?

Classes (jars) compiled using JDK 1.8 can be executed in JDK 1.8+ environments (JDK 11, JDK 17). However, classes (jars) compiled using JDK 11 cannot be executed in JDK 1.8 environments.

Free IDE tools: Eclipse, NetBeans, IDEA Community all support Maven-based projects.

What stops you from updating your project to Java 11 or later?

We cannot update JDK environment because of the policy. Do I have to find the latest version of each dependency that can run on Java 1.8 one by one?

@KA957 Yes, you have to find the latest version of each dependency that can run on Java 1.8 one by one. If you want software that requires the latest versions of Java, you must deploy to the latest versions of Java.

Do note that having to stick to Java 8 means you miss out on a lot of new language features and improvements to the JVM (like for the garbage collection and whatever else). Also, as you've noticed, some libraries are compiled with later versions so you could end up with more problems if you can't upgrade (security risks, not being able to use features that you need, ...).

If your company has a policy that you can't upgrade beyond Java 8, then you should address that. It makes no sense to be stuck when the current long-term support version is Java 21.

@JFabianMeier I'm inclined to agree. Of course, there is a tool, and that is the Maven versions plugin, though I currently see no way to limit version updates by compilation target VM version

Later software requires later Java
If you want software that requires the latest versions of Java, you must deploy to the latest versions of Java.
Otherwise, you will have to find the latest version of each dependency that can run on Java 8, one by one.
Class File Format
Technically, when a JVM loads a class for execution, it checks the Class File Format version of that class. If the code was compiled with a later compiler, the class will be marked with a higher Class File Format version. If that version number is higher than the one supported by your JVM, then an error occurs.
To see which Class File Format version maps to which version of Java, see the table in the Wikipedia article Java version history.
In your case, Java 8 compiles to Class File Format version 52. Any class with a Class File Format version of 53 or later will not run.



Java
Class File Format




(LTS) 8
52


9
53


…
…


(LTS) 21
65


…
…


23
67



